# SYSGEN_SYSISAPI replacement for WinCE6

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm currently porting a CE5 platform to CE6. It's a headless system and until
now I've made great use of the "Device Management ISAPI Extension"
(SYSGEN_SYSISAPI), mostly for launching and killing processes. So I was
alarmed that this catalog item seems to have disappeared in CE6 Platform
Builder. There doesn't seem to be any explanation on MSDN why MS removed this.
Is there an obvious alternative that I should be using?

TIA

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually adding the SYSGEN to the platform?  It wouldn't be the first time something was dropped from the catalog, but that can still be included manually.